# vue 3 composition API, conditional rendering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a button that needs to change it's icon when clicked in order to toggle between play and pause.

Here is a minimalistic sample of the code :

```
<template>

    <div @click="toggleF">
        <i v-if="toggleForce == true" class="fas fa-pause"></i>
        <i v-if="toggleForce == false" class="fas fa-play"></i>
    </div>

</template>
```

```
<script>
    import {onMounted, onBeforeMount, ref} from 'vue'

    export default {
        setup(){
            const toggleForce = ref(false)

            function toggleF () {
               toggleForce.value = !toggleForce.value
            };

        return {toggleF,toggleForce}
        }
    }
</script>
```

I get the following warning/error :
[image]

Comment: Which version of Vue are you using? I had a similar problem on early versions of Vue3

Comment: You can simplify the class with something like this:  `:class="['fas', toggleForce ? 'fa-pause' : 'fa-play']"`

Answer (score 2):

please try the code below:

#### demo 1

```html
<template>
  <div @click="toggleForce = !toggleForce">
    <i v-if="toggleForce" class="fas fa-pause" />
    <i v-else class="fas fa-play" />
   </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'

const toggleForce = ref(false)
</script>
```

the `<script setup>` tag is available since the [vue version 3.2](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3.2.html) and will help you to clean up your script area

---

#### demo 2

```js
const { ref, createApp } = Vue

createApp({
  setup() {
    const toggleForce = ref(false)

    const toggleF = () => {
      toggleForce.value = !toggleForce.value
    }

    return {
      toggleForce, 
      toggleF
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggleF">toggleForce
    <div v-if="toggleForce == true" class="fas fa-pause">TRUE</div>
    <div v-if="toggleForce == false" class="fas fa-play">FALSE</div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Switching the v-if to use the toggleForce == true worked for me.